# PHP Composer dependency of library

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm developing a PHP-App using composer.
Now I need a PHP-Libary, which is also developed by me.
Inside the IDE there is no problem using the library-classes. But when the app is running inside Apache2 I need to install the library via "composer update".
But when I change some library-class I always need to reinstall the new code via composer. Before that I have to push my changes to the SCM.
Is there a way to simplify this process during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out symlinks, the solution for me is symlinking the dependend library with ln -s TARGET NAME. Adding the dependency to composer.json is for generating the classmaps and running without errors after deleting the symlink. It works fine. Also a "composer update" is working without overriding the symlink. New classes are found immedeately without doing the whole process described in the question.